# How to fetch partial data in some limit from large data table?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to fetch some range of data from large data table.

My table struture is : **child_table**

```
`clustering_key` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`Parent_id` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

`child_id` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

`data` text, 

`position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

PRIMARY KEY (`clustering_key`),

UNIQUE KEY `child_index` (`child_id`) USING BTREE,

KEY `position_index` (`position`),

FULLTEXT KEY `data_index` (`data`), 

CONSTRAINT `FK_child_table_parent_table` FOREIGN KEY (`Parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent_table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) 

ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let assume sample data is :

[image]

In this table Position column have order of child data and its changed according to operation like up/down,insert and delete.

So, In the above example 9 child rows of same parent. I want to fetch from 3 to 6 child data in order of position.

When i try to execute query

```
Select *
FROM child_table
where Parent_id='8c002adc-9a1c-4eeb-94b6-72d3e30c3862'
order by Position
limit 3,6;
```

This query giving me right data but MySql scan 9 rows for this. Let assume Parent have 90000 data so mysql scan all 90000 rows for giving me data.

So, I want to avoid all row scanning for fetching data.

Please give me solution for this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.